# F11 act like left mouseclick with Autohotkey, and F12 as right mouseclick?

Tags: autohotkey

I try to get <kbd>F11</kbd> act as [left mouseclick], with Autohotkey, and <kbd>F12</kbd> as right mouseclick.

I tried the beneath script. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, or can't it be done?

```
F11::Send mouseClick left
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question [here](http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/54265-make-a-key-on-the-keyboard-like-left-click/).

```
F11::
Send {LButton Down}
KeyWait F11
Send {LButton Up}
Return

F12::
Send {RButton Down} 
KeyWait F12 
Send {RButton Up}
Return
```

And the explanation I found on that site:

```
a:: ;"a" key on key board :)
Send {LButton Down} ;Press left mouse button
KeyWait a ;wait for release of "a"
Send {LButton Up} ;release Left Mouse button
Return ;End Hotkey
```